# angular unit test stateful filter

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a filter that depends upon a service to retrieve some configuration, and hence I have made the filter stateful. It works great! However, I'd like to add unit tests around it but can't work out how to implement them.

An example filter:

```
.filter("myFilter", function(myService) {
  var data = null, serviceInvoked = false;

  function realFilter(value) {
    return data + value;
  }

  filterStub.$stateful = true;
  function filterStub(value) {
    if( data === null ) {
      if( !serviceInvoked ) {
        console.log('no state'); // dirty console.log for unit test diagnostics
        serviceInvoked = true;
        myService.get().then(function(result){
           data = result;
        });
      }
      return "-";
    }
    else {
      return realFilter(value);
    }
  }

  return filterStub;
});
```

I can test that "-" is initially returned.

In my next test I have stubbed *myService* with sinonjs and return a promise. I want to resolve that promise with *data* and see that the filter updates correctly. My test looks something like:

```
it('returns the value prepended with the data from the service', 
  function () {
    $scope.value = "World!";
    var markup = "<div>{{value | myFilter}}</div>";
    var element = $compile(markup)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    /*
     * Works:
     */
    expect(element.html()).toBe('-');

    /*
     * the following still returns "-" though I want to test 
     * that realFilter was executed
     */
    myServiceMock_getPromise.resolve('Hello ');
    $scope.$digest();

    // FAIL: Expected '-' to be 'Hello World!'
    expect(element.html()).toBe('Hello World!');
});
```

This works in production, but in the unit test the console.log in the filter  outputs 'no state' with each digest, *implying* its not maintaining the filters state.

Is there something about the way I am compiling the markup that eludes to it being unable to maintain state or have I got something wrong with my test?

Comment: What does your test look like so far? I don't think anyone is going to just write the test for you. Also you didn't ask a question.

Comment: Thanks @PrestonVanLoon, I've added my failing test, and with a little more info (regarding no saving of state) I've added a question. Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about template compilation. It's about promises and javascript ticks.

Resolved promise will be executed in a different tick (regardless `$scope.$digest` which only initiates this process). Thus expectations should be wrapped in `.then` and test engine should be notified about the fact that the test is asynchronous by `done` callback.

```
it('returns the value prepended with the data from the service', 
  function (done) {
    ...

    myServiceMock_getPromise.resolve('Hello ');
    $scope.$digest();
    myServiceMock_getPromise.promise.then(function(){
       expect(element.html()).toBe('Hello World!');
       done();
    });
 }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)
I had to make a couple of changes though:

1. The assertion had to be connected to the promise prior to resolving the promise.

2. I had to put the assertion on the next tick (setTimeout( ..., 1)) in order for the promise to be handled in the filter first.

Comment: That's surprising that you had to use `setTimeout`... are you using `$q`?